# Retrieve only specific keys from collection

Tags: firebase

I would like to store an array of notes, where each note contains a title and a body. Is it possible to retrieve the list of note titles without the body?

For example:

```
notes: [
  ewi4ef36wi: {
    title: 'Shopping List',
    body: 'todo'
  }
  o9kng23inw: {
    title: 'Things To Do',
    body: ''
  }
]
```

How could I just retrieve the list of titles?

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Firebase's Web/JavaScript API always returns the full tree under the nodes that you request.

The most common workaround for this is that people set up a secondary branch in the tree where they just keep the keys.

```
Notes
    1: { "body": "hello", "title": "yessir" }
    2: { "body": "again", "title": "title2" }
    3: { "body": "there", "title": "another" }
Notes_index
    1: true
    2: true
    3: true
```

This is commonly referred to as an index. You'd `on('child_added'` on `Notes_index` and then (if needed) get the content of each note using `once('value'`.

Indexes are also often used to make nodes accessible by an alternative key. Such as a title index for the above:

```
Title_index
    "another": 3
    "title2": 2
    "yessir": 1
```

This last structure might soon not be needed anymore, since Firebase is extending their query API to allow ordering/filtering on any field. But for your use-case an index is still useful.

Comment: Great answer, Frank! One amendment: You can retrieve a list of keys without fetching all the data using [shallow=true](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-rest-uri-params) via the REST API. This has some limitations around millions of nodes, but can be an alternative.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that. It would be nice if the Web/JavaScript API had a similar feature. Then again: I love the simplicity of the current web API. Just the right number of features.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, when you set the title or body values for the note be sure to [set a priority](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/setwithpriority.html). You can then [bind to the notes endpoint (receive events and data) limited to keys matching a specified priority](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/equalto.html).

Comment: That will allow you to retrieve fewer nodes, but not fewer levels of a node. I didn't know there was an `equalTo` btw, that sounds more efficient than my usual trick of starting and ending with the same value: `startAt('value').endAt('value')`

Comment: I should have been more specific with my question :) What I wanted WAS fewer nodes (just the title ones for example). I'll leave both answers as-is as they both offer valuable information. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Can you share the code that will allow you to retrieve just the titles from the data structure in the question?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen For example I'm storing titles with no priority and the note content with a priority of 1. The following with retrieve the note titles only: `new Firebase("https://example.firebaseio.com/").child('notes').equalTo(null)`.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't make that work without switching the data structure from what you have in your original question. Can you make this jsbin work the way you describe?  http://jsbin.com/vobeb/1/edit?js,console