# firebase: retrieve specific fields from object

Tags: javascript, firebase

I am using firebase for storing data of players. I want to show only statistics of all the players 
I have structure like:

`players:{
    [playerId]:{
        info:{
            firstName: 'Jon',
            lastName: 'Mark',
            otherInfo:'aaa'
        },
        OtherTooMuchInfo:{},
        stats:{
            totalPlayed: 10,
            scoreCountA: 14,
            scoreCountB: 24,
        }
    },
    [playerId]:{
        info:{
            firstName: 'Hen',
            lastName: 'Lee',
            otherInfo:'qwe'
        },
        OtherTooMuchInfo:{},
        stats:{
            totalPlayed: 33,
            scoreCountA: 12,
            scoreCountB: 43,
        }
    }
}`

How can I retrieve only `stats` of all the players from firebase without loading all other information?

Comment: Hi vinesh, with the Web/JavaScript API you can only retrieve full nodes. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26689437/209103

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieve only specific keys from collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685610/retrieve-only-specific-keys-from-collection)